# Canon MX490 Ubuntu 20.04 : printing problem

Tags: printing

Just installed clean 20.04.
Canon's MX490 Scanner works great but I cant print..
I reinstalled the printer with the same problem.
The printer works fine through WiFi.

Thanks for your help.

Ruben

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem, albeit with a Pixma mp230

Try this simple solution, which I found on distrowatch.com' s [user rating page of Ubuntu 20.04](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=ratings&distro=ubuntu)  (the review dated 2020-08-19):

1. remove ippusbxd (`sudo apt remove ippusbxd` in terminal)
2. delete and reinstall the printer using the normal GUI printer utility
3. Print a test page. Worked for me!

The proposed theory behind it is that ippusbxd "creates" a "ubuntu"-printer which interferes with the original printer/printer drivers (in the reviewer's case a Brothers printer, in my case a Canon Pixma mp230).

I am incredibly thankful to the original problemsolver for this simple solution and thought I would pay it forward here, where more people might see it.