# Canon MX330, Ubuntu 20.04 (after upgrade from 18.04) - Printing not working - Scanning Does Work

Tags: upgrade, printing, canon

Recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and found that I can no longer print.
Printer is Cannon MX330 via USB.
Scanning via Document Scanning tool works fine.

Found a post  - [Canon MX490 Ubuntu 20.04 : printing problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238114/canon-mx490-ubuntu-20-04-printing-problem)
Followed the instructions but still same issue, no printing but scanning works.

Has anyone seen similar and able to correct it.

Thanks
Jas

Comment: Please accept one of the answers (maybe yours) as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Printing is supported by `printer-driver-gutenprint`. It shouldn't be too difficult to set up a print queue from (say) `localhost:631`, as described [here](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSPrintQueues#webinterface).

Also, `ippusbxd` is suboptimal. Although your Canon is too old to use it, it is probably best to keep it off your system.

Personally, I would do the following to set up a print queue:

`lpinfo -m | grep MX330`. This gives you a PPD to substitute. It begins `gutenprint` and ends with `expert`.

Now you need a URI. Use `lpinfo -v` and read the page given in the link above. Now substitute for the PPD and URI in `lpadmin -p PRINTQ -v "URI" -E -m PPD`. PRINTQ can be any name you want to give to the queue. How's that?

Comment: Appreciate the feedback and accessed CUPS interface - localhost:631/admin    I can see the printer - under List of Available (Canon MX330) but haven't found a compatible "Model" that works. Several "Models" that I have tried seem to work - i.e. on the Printer LED it displays "Printing from PC" but never prints.

Comment: @JAS I have added to my answer.

Comment: I needn't have bothered adding to my answer. There isn't any engagement. Typical askubuntu. Nobody learns.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to get the Canon MX330 printing again under 20.04.

1. At this link - https://canon-print.com/canon-pixma-mx330-driver-series-windows-mac-linux/

   Downloaded Linux - Debian Version 3.1

   This file - `cnijfilter-mx330series-3.10-1-i386-deb.tar.gz` saved to Downloads.
   Extract the file to folder `cnijfilter-mx330series-3.10-1-i386-deb`.
2. At this link - [https://launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk](https://launchpad.net/%7Emichael-gruz/+archive/ubuntu/canon-trunk). This is PPA (Personal Package Archive) for Canon printers.

   Ran these commands:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. This will complain about the repository not being secure. To correct this
   Modified the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

   Original file

   ```
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu focal main
   # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu focal main
   ```

   Updated file

   ```
   # deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu focal main
   # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu focal main
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu trusty main
   deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu trusty main
   ```
4. Updated the file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-vendor-ubuntu` added this line at the end:

   ```
   Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories "true";
   ```
5. Ran the previous "sudo" commands again. The following error noted on the "update" command:

   ```
   W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: 
   84E550CD36EC35430A66AC5A03396E1C3F7B4A1D
   W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu trusty Release' is not signed.
   N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
   N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
   ```
6. Ran command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp550series
   ```
7. Then ran the install.sh located in the Directort Downloads/cnijfilter-mx330series-3.10-1-i386-deb

   ```
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```

   ```
   Execution command = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter-common_3.10-1_i386.deb
   dpkg: will not downgrade cnijfilter-common:i386 from 3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1 to 3.10-1, skipping
   Execution command = sudo dpkg -iG ./packages/cnijfilter-mx330series_3.10-1_i386.deb
   Selecting previously unselected package cnijfilter-mx330series:i386.
   (Reading database ... 227623 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack .../cnijfilter-mx330series_3.10-1_i386.deb ...
   Unpacking cnijfilter-mx330series:i386 (3.10-1) ...
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cnijfilter-mx330series:i386:
   cnijfilter-mx330series:i386 depends on libtiff4.
   dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-mx330series:i386 (--install):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

   Errors were encountered while processing:
   cnijfilter-mx330series:i386
   Execution command = sudo dpkg -P cnijfilter-common
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of cnijfilter-common:i386:
   cnijfilter-mx330series:i386 depends on cnijfilter-common (>= 3.10).
   cnijfilter-mp550series:i386 depends on cnijfilter-common (>= 3.90).
   dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-common:i386 (--purge): dependency problems - not removing
   Errors were encountered while processing:
   cnijfilter-common:i386
   ```

   Need to install cnijfilter-common
8. `sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-common`

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree   
   Reading state information... Done
   cnijfilter-common:i386 is already the newest version (3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1).
   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   cnijfilter-mx330series:i386 : Depends: libtiff4:i386 but it is not installable
   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
   ```
9. Ran `fix-broken` :

   ```
   sudo apt --fix-broken install
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree 
   Reading state information... Done
   Correcting dependencies... Done
   The following additional packages will be installed:
   cnijfilter-mx330series:i386
   The following packages will be upgraded:
   cnijfilter-mx330series:i386
   1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
   1 not fully installed or removed.
   Need to get 1,028 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 502 kB disk space will be freed.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 

   WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
   cnijfilter-mx330series:i386
   Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
   Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-gruz/canon-trunk/ubuntu trusty/main i386 cnijfilter-mx330series i386 3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1 [1,028 kB]
   Fetched 1,028 kB in 2s (567 kB/s)            
   (Reading database ... 227821 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack .../cnijfilter-mx330series_3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1_i386.deb ...
   Unpacking cnijfilter-mx330series:i386 (3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1) over (3.10-1) ...
   Setting up cnijfilter-mx330series:i386 (3.90-76~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
   Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
   ```
10. Finally go to the URL localhost:631 .

    - under Administration select FIND PRINTER
    - select Canon_MX330_series
    - select Canon
    - for model selected Canon MX330 series Ver.3.90
    - once added under MAINTENANCE selet PRINT TEST PAGE
11. Clean up the repositories.

    - Remove the line - Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories "true";
      from /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01-vendor-ubuntu
    - Open SOFTWARE and UPDATES
    - select OTHER SOFTWARE
    - locate the "michael-gruz/canon-trunk" and click REMOVE, cache will be updated
    - optionally run apt-get update