# Upgraded from 20.04lts to 22.04.1lts, Canon PIXMA MX330, printing no longer works

Tags: canon

Printer Canon PIXMA MX330, printing no longer works on 22.04.1 LTS.
The SCAN application, works fine to this printer.
Both print and scan worked on 20.04 LTS.
When I upgraded to 20.04 I found this answer/URL that I used to resolve issues on the
20.04 version, i.e. at that time, scan and printing did not work.
[Canon MX330, Ubuntu 20.04 (after upgrade from 18.04) - Printing not working - Scanning Does Work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1317560/canon-mx330-ubuntu-20-04-after-upgrade-from-18-04-printing-not-working-sc)

Within the link above I basically reran several of the commands but probably the key command

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mp550series
```

returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package cnijfilter-mp550series:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'cnijfilter-mp550series:i386' has no installation candidate
```

Anyone have similar printer or issue ?

Thanks much,
Jas

Comment: Is the printer attached via USB or networked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install printer-driver-gutenprint`

then open http://localhost:631/admin and delete and re-add printer here.

I recommend to log to CUPS in Firefox. (Chrome and Vivaldi sometimes doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.....that did it, printing is now working !!!

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as solved.